# Cant set default program to open file type in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

I have netbeans installed on ubuntu. In netbeans I can go file, open file, and then navigate to the type of file I want to open (in my case a .php file).

However if I go to a php file in a folder I cant get it to open with netbeans. If I right click and select open with other application, show other applications, then I dont have net beans in the list.

If I right click the file and go to properties, open with, then I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might depend on your file browser/file manager (e.g. the programs are called nautilus in gnome, thor in xfce..., find out using the "help" menu entry).

Most likely however you can right-mouse-click-"Open with ..." and type in the path of the program you want to open the file with. To find the path of your netbeans installation type `which netbeans` or `whereis netbeans` in a terminal. I would guess you will find it in /usr/bin/netbeans , but it seems to be in something like [/usr/local/netbeans-7.0.1/bin/netbeans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26379/where-is-netbeans-installed-on-ubuntu) . Also, please provide which flavor (e.g. Xubuntu 12.04) of ubuntu you run.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300852/setting-default-editor-for-php-files/305408#305408?newreg=ef1c08661d18488c83901453ec91a751) installing and using `thunar` might help

> `sudo apt-get install thunar`
>
> Running thunar in terminal and using it for default application would be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Command to Add Netbeans in Open With Menu and Default Editor:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/netbeans.desktop
```

Now Paste following Code on the Editor and Save It :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Netbeans
Comment=Netbeans IDE
Exec=/home/compaq/netbeans-8/bin/netbeans [Here you have to paste your Netbeans Path]
Icon=/home/compaq/netbeans-8/nb/netbeans.png [paste your Netbeans logo path]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development,IDE;
StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your file manager but this should work:

- 'Right-click' on the file
- then 'Properties'
- then 'Open With'
- then select 'Netbeans' in the list of applications
- 'Set as default'